# How to create a tree-hierarchical structure with unique behavior for every type combination?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Assume:

1. There is some module whose interface is `IA`.
2. There is some module `B`, that takes in a parameter an instance of `IA`, and whose behavior depends upon the type of that `IA`,

meaning (pseudo code, no specific language)

```
class B{
    IA ia;
    B(IA ia){
        this.ia = ia;
    }
    doStuff(){
        if(type(this.ia)==A1){
             print("A1");
        }
        if(type(this.ia)==A2){
             print("A2");
        }
    }
}
```

I realize I could add some public method `foo` to `ia`, and thus the code would simplify to

```
class B{
    IA ia;
    B(IA ia){
        this.ia = ia;
    }
    doStuff(){
        this.ia.foo();
    }
}
```

**My question is twofold:**

1. What is the correct design to achieve this if I (for some reason) can't change `IA`, meaning, I can't add `foo()`?
2. What is the correct (scalable) design if I am allowed to change `IA` but the same problem now repeats for `A1`, `A2`, and so on, meaning

the final desired behavior is

```
class B{
    IA ia;
    B(IA ia){
        this.ia = ia;
    }
    doStuff(){
        if(type(this.ia)==A1){
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z1){
                 print("A1Z1");
                 print("unique treatment");
             }
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z2){
                 print("A1Z2");
                 print("special treatment");
             }
        }
        if(type(this.ia)==A2){
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z1){
                 print("Z1A2");
                 print("one of a kind treatment");
             }
             if(type(this.ia.iz)==Z2){
                 print("Z2A2");
                 print("Wow treatment");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

and can repeat more times.

**Please notice Z1 and Z1 are the same for A1 and A2!**. And again, the same can go on, `IZ` can contain `IX` of several types, with unique behaviors

I wonder if case 2 is at all separate of modular, in the sense that, the behavior is unique for every type-combination, and no behavior can really be extracted to a more abstract level.

I still don't like the type checking, and wonder if there is something that can be done which looks better.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "double dispatch". Available design alternatives may depend on the programming language you are using, try to google "double dispatch [your favorite programming language].

Comment: From your description ("And again, the same can go on"), I get the sense that you actually need *multiple* dispatch (as in, more then double); but maybe there's an alternative approach. BTW, is this more of a hypothetical question or are you actually trying to work with a library that has a type hierarchy that doesn't quite fit what you need to do? You can probably arrange things so that you are not relying on *that* hierarchy and work with concrete types instead, but can you give us more info (more context)?

Comment: This is really hard to answer when it's this abstract.  Can you not provide a more concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to create a new interface with `foo()` and then wrapper types for that interface that contain the specific logic you want for each type.  Then it's simply a matter of wrapping each IA instance.

Depending on how these `IA` instances are created, you may not be able to do this without checking the type at the point of wrapping.  This therefore may not eliminate the need to do type checking but it will allow you to keep that bit of nastiness in confined to method that does nothing else.  Then that allows your `B` class to work the way you desire.

A similar but different approach would be to create B classes that correspond to each IA type you want to deal with differently.  Then, just like above, you need some code to check the type of the IA in order to get the appropriate B type but it's separate from the application logic.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the visitor design pattern. It looks to me that it may apply to the problem you are trying to solve, whereby your IA would be the root of the complex data structure that you want to visit with a logic dependent upon its static and/or dynamic type shape, and which is seemingly subject to evolution.